# Keras: fitting a DNN gives non-zero mean error

Tags: keras

I'm training a very simple DNN, but I found that the mean error after sufficient training is not close to 0:

```
def meanError(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(y_true - y_pred)

def stdError(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.std(y_true - y_pred)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, activation='tanh', input_shape=(numFeatures,)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='tanh'))
rmsp = optimizers.rmsprop(lr=0.0001)
model.compile(optimizer=rmsp,loss='mse', metrics=[meanError, stdError])
model.fit(cxTrain, yTrain, epochs = 10, batch_size = 1024, verbose=0)

score = model.evaluate(cxTrain, yTrain, verbose=0)
print(score)
```

This gives me mean error of -4.177 and standard deviation of 6.589. The standard deviation in my case is very good, but I'm expecting the mean error to be very close to 0. I changed my optimizer to adam and I got -3.908 mean error, so I guess it is not optimizer dependent. Also, increase epoch seem to reduce standard deviation but not necessarily the mean error. May I know if I'm missing anything important to reduce the mean error? Thanks!

Comment: You are using a 'tanh` activation function. Are your outputs scaled between -1 and 1?

Comment: If I remove tanh from the output layer, I will get higher error mean and standard deviations...